# How to change accordion template by ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am now developing AngularJS based web application and have trouble to realize this.

Please see this image.

[image]

As you can see here, I need to display utterly different template when I click any item on accordion.

```
<accordion close-others="true" >
          <accordion-group  is-open="isopen"
              ng-repeat="account in vm.accounts"
              ng-controller="AccountController">
              <accordion-heading>    
                <div class="row" ng-click="templateChange({{isopen}})">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <i class="pull-right glyphicon"
                            ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-up': isopen, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !isopen}"></i>
                        {{ ::account.name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
                        <p class="text-uppercase">Balance</p>
                        ${{ ::account.balance }}
                        <p class="text-uppercase">Annual Return</p>
                        {{ ::account.annualReturn }}%
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                    </div>
                </div>    
              </accordion-heading>
          </accordion-group>
```

And this is the controller part but still empty.

```
function AccountController($scope) {

    $scope.templateChange = function(isOpen){
      // Here, I hope to know what should I wrote to use another templatge
    }

}
```

So, I hope to know how to change the template of individual accordion-group when I click it to expand or collapse.

Please help me!!!

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you could provide a plunker.

Comment: Ok, then please don't care about the code, and please teach me how to change the template on accordion-group if you click it based on the image only.

Comment: Based on your image, I would recommend to use angular ui https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ This give you a much better control and integration of business logic and DOM manipulation.

Comment: Yes, I am now using it, but what I want to know is how to change the template of accordion, e.g, uib-accordion-heading's template by ng-click.